# Excel VBA isolate Unique dates when you have time with it

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to create an array or range of unique dates from a column of dates that have time associated with it. For example

```
1/3/1984 0:15
1/3/1984 0:20
1/4/1984 0:25
1/4/1984 0:30
1/6/1984 0:35
1/6/1984 0:40
```

The range would return

```
 1/3/1984
 1/4/1984
 1/6/1984
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the prettiest solution with the error handling but it should give you a collection of unique dates.  An error is generated and ignored when adding another date with the same key.  Convert the collection to an array or a range as needed,

```
Sub uniqueDates()
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim c As Collection
    Dim cell As Range

    Set inputRange = Range("A1:A6")
    Set c = New Collection

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each cell In inputRange
        c.Add DateValue(cell.Value), CStr(DateValue(cell.Value))
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you I shall try this. I had another smaller question. I have a dynamic range that changes based on the data set. I have attempted to use "Dim rd As Range
    Dim nr As Long
    Set rd = Sheets("Raw Data").Range("b2", Range("b2").End(xlDown))
    nr = rd.Rows.Count" but I get a 1004 error

Comment: @Tree Couldn't recreate your error (even though the syntax in the third line looks weird to me).  Maybe ask a new question with some more details, like which line the error happens on.